# how to load data to recursive dataView in extjs?

Tags: templates, extjs, recursion, store, dataview

I have a recursive template.

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for="."><div>'+
            '<div class="select">{text}</div>'+
            '{[this.putChildren(values)]}'+
            ' </div></tpl>'
            ,
            {
                putChildren:function(values){


                    if(values.children){
                        Ext.each(values.children,function(child,index,arr){
                        return this.apply(values.children);
                    }


                })
```

I set itemSelector:'select'

The thing is that when I load the data I get an error "records[i] is undefined" and when I set a listener the event is fired on every click but I get item=undefined on every node except the root.
I cant set a treeStore because dataview only excepts store or jsonstore. (maybe I'm doing something wrong?)

so I have a simple question how can I draw a tree using data view and a store?
I couldn't find any good recourse for this...

actually I have a template like this

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhBjMws1H10&t=35m52s
I just cant load the data correctly...

do I need Store or TreeStore or something else?

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

So why not use tree Panel? 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel

Comment: I have a custom template that actually doesn't work like a tree. it's more like a diagram then tree.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever solved this problem? Having the exact same issue. Although I haven't spent a lot of time with it for now.

Maybe it's useful for you to iterate directly through the children.
So, instead of

```
<tpl for=".">
```

i think you can directly use

```
<tpl for="children">
```

This makes it possible to use *values* as a variable already for each child.